# Cannot borrow `*s` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference `s` is a `&` reference

Tags: rust

I am pretty new to rust. And I am getting stuck on the following code.

```
    let mut all_iterators: Vec<Chars> = Vec::new();
    for s in strings {
        let a = s.chars();
        all_iterators.push(a);
    }

    let common_str: &str = "";
    loop {
        let common_char: Option<char>;

        for s in &all_iterators {
            if let Some(temp) = (*s).next() {}
        }
    }
```

Getting the following error on `(*s).next()`

```
cannot borrow `*s` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
`s` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

Any help will be appreciated. And can you please explain where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: `for mut s in all_iterators.clone() { if let Some(temp) = s.next() {} }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for s in &all_iterators` means that `s` has a type `&Chars` (that is you are iterating over **immutable** references). But calling `next` on an iterator requires **mutable** reference (because it will modify the underling iterator). So you must at least iterate over mutable references to `Chars`. Try this instead:

```rust
for s in &mut all_iterators {
    // ...
}
```